# How can I limit the length of a row selection when using Excel.Range()

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using VB.net code to manipulate Excel documents.  I'm trying to grab a range of cells contained in a single specific row.  I don't know the specific end cell, I just need All the cells that contain values in that row.

Here is a basic example of what i've been doing up to this point:

> Dim rngRange as Excel.Range
>
> Dim wksXLWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
>
> rngRange = wksXLWorksheet.Range("A1").EntireRow

I know that row containing the Range "A1" (which is a single cell) is the row that I want, and so I use the EntireRow property to return the entire row.  It returns all the cells, including the unused ones, so over 16k in cells, most of them empty.

How can choose a range with only the used the Cells?  I don't want to use UsedRange because that grabs everything, I only want the one row, and only up to where the cells no longer contain data.

Also, if i select a limited range like this, will it have more or less impact on resources?  I was assuming it would have less impact selecting the small range, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use .End property, e.g. Range("A1").End(xlToRight).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that was simple.  I had looked at the end property in some online documentation but I ended up skipping over it when it didn't work the way I expected; that was before I got to my current understanding of ranges..  Thanks!

Comment: @meltdownmonk -> While this is a good answer, a better solution might be this: `rngRange = wksXLWorksheet.Cells(1, wksXLWorksheet.Range("A" & wksXLWorksheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)` This syntax moves from the last column to the left to find the *real* row end, were as the starting from cell `A1` and moving to the right `xlToRight` will stop at the first random blank cell that shows up, should there be any.

Comment: I don't think this completely answered the question...  This only returns the last used cell in the row, not all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel.Application object has an Intersect method and the worksheet has a UsedRange property.

```
Dim rngRange as Excel.Range
Dim wksXLWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

rngRange = Excel.Intersect(wksXLWorksheet.Range("1:1"), wksXLWorksheet.UsedRange)
```

Alternately, define the range with the start and end points while qualifying the Cells that make up the Range.

```
Dim rngRange as Excel.Range
Dim wksXLWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

rngRange = wksXLWorksheet.Range(wksXLWorksheet.Range("A1"), wksXLWorksheet.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft))
```